# URL address is Strikethrough when running Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

I am running automation test on local url, after some time (happening randomly)
url is strike-through for unknown reason and due to that , the site keeps on loading and test fails.

[image]

using these confg-
**chrom**e-60.0.3xx 
**chromedriver**-2.29
**selenium webriver**- 2.53.x

Do anyone has some explanation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like two separate problems - [the crossed out url is basically Chrome's indication of a security issue](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/85698/58553), but the site keeping loading feels like a different problem..have you tried to adjust/increase loading timeouts?

Comment: yup with no success

Comment: Can you reproduce the same problem if you navigate to this exact url in the browser manually?

Comment: manually it is working fine, no strikethrough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found was quitting the chromedriver as there was multiple processes of chromedriver running.

Killing the process is best solution I get. Use the Task scheduler to end the process of chromedriver.

Comment: It sounds like there is a different issue that is causing your chromedriver processes to remain. Unless an unexpected error occurred, the chromedriver process should be ended automatically when test execution is finished.